# converting Perl to R stats question f probability question

Tags: r, perl

I am trying to convert Perl code to R I think qf is the function I need to use however in the case below the PERL fprob=.42870 and qf=NAN , any ideas hon how I can get this working.

```
R
      fprob<-qf(1.36111111111361, df1=72, df2=4) #=NAN
PERL
      my $fprob=Statistics::Distributions::fprob (72,4,1.36111111111361); #=0.42870

Definition:
$fprob=Statistics::Distributions::fprob (3,5,.625);
print "upper probability of the F distribution (3 degrees of freedom "
     ."in numerator, 5 degrees of freedom in denominator, F = 6.25): "
     ."Q = 1-G = $fprob\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fprob` is the upper probability of the distribution and `qf` is the quantile function. The are not the same.
Try

```
> 1-pf(1.36111111111361, df1=72, df2=4)
[1] 0.4286957
```

Relevant documentation:

> ‘df’ gives the density, ‘pf’ gives the distribution function ‘qf’
> gives the quantile function, and ‘rf’ generates random deviates.

Comment: Hey Raja , thanks you so much that is the answer!